# How to use django default login

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication

I'm trying to use django's default admin login function. This works for logging out, i.e. putting in html:

```html
<a href="{% url "log_out" %}">
```

and in `urls.py`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView

path("log_in/", LoginView.as_view(), name="log_in"),
path("log_out/", LogoutView.as_view(), name="log_out"),
```

clicking on the logout link takes the user to the django logout page and works correctly. But trying to do the equivalent to log in, i.e.:

```html
<a href="{% url "log_in" %}">
```

causes a `TemplateDoesNotExist` error. I would like to use django's default login page rather than creating my own template - how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The directory listing in `TEMPLATES` should look like this:

##### Django version 3.1 or earlier:

```py
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

##### Django 3.2 and later:

```py
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
```

Note: take care to delete browser cache.

Comment: Nothing seems to have changed. Am i correct in assuming this is the TEMPLATES variable in settings.py?

Comment: Yes, this var is in settings module.

Comment: You define your pathes in main urls.py module or in an app? If you define them in an app have you registered your app in the INSTALLED_APPS?